# Nested view required

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I am new in drupal.

I want to create a view in drupal-6 for my three content types which are integrated with each other by node reference(CCK).
I have contents types
1) Topic
2) Room
3) Time slot

I want the schedule to be grouped by topic (a field in the room node), then by room name, thusly:

```
* [topic 1]
      o [room 1]
            + [timeslot 1 & related data in class]
            + [timeslot 2 & related data in class]
      o [room 2]
            + [timeslot 1 & related data in class]
            + [timeslot 2 & related data in class]
* [topic 2]
      o [room 1]
            + [timeslot 1 & related data in class]
```

Thanks in advance,
Kashif

Comment: You can use views for Topics, but for rooms and timeslots you may draw manually via theming if views.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will work, but two possibilities come to my mind:

1. create a view of the room nodes, add a relationship with the timeslot nodes and group by the topic nodes.
2. create a view of topic nodes, add a relationship with the room nodes and add a relationship with timeslot nodes on the first relationship.